# Facebook API - Get image URL after I upload it

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know how to get image url or any other data besides id when I upload it to facebook via graph API. I tried to get image data from Graph API Explorer but it gives me `false`. When I put my `access_token` with `user_photos` it gives me details. However, default access token that I can get from `$facebook->getAccessToken();` still gives me `false`.

So my question is - How can I get image data after I upload it to facebook?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

require 'fb/src/facebook.php';

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 0)
{
    // Getting
    $file = $_FILES["file"];
    $fileExtension = $imgExtension = end(explode(".", $file["name"]));
    $upload_dir = "upload/";

    // Modifying
    $newName = md5(uniqid()) . "." . $fileExtension;

    // Checking if this name already exists
    while (file_exists($upload_dir . $newName) == true)
    {
        $newName = md5(uniqid()) . "." . $fileExtension;
    }

    // Uploading
    if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $upload_dir . $newName) == true)
    {
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                    'appId' => 'app id',
                    'secret' => 'app secret',
                ));

        $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
        $args = array(
            "message" => "test caption"
        );

        $args['image'] = '@' . realpath($upload_dir . $newName);

        $data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
        print_r($data);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the `id` of uploaded photo in the response (`$data` in your case), simple call to Graph API with that `id` should return you all the desired info.

```
$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
$photo_data = json_decode($data, true);
$photo = $facebook->api('/'.$photo_data['id']);

$thumbnail = $photo['picture'];
$large_photo = $photo['source'];
$photo_page = $photo['link'];
```

**Update:**  You should require `user_photos` to read [`photo`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) object details.

Comment: When I try it like that it returns nothing.

Comment: Do you have `id` of photo uploaded in response? What [OpenGraph Explorer tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) return for that `id`?

Comment: It returns 'false'. Only when I enter access_token with 'user_photos' enabled I get image data.

Comment: Well, requiring `user_photos` permission is the only way to get details of photo of user.

Comment: Yea, I figured that.. but where can I do that? In my application settings or some other place?

Comment: Or maybe somehow I can make it upload photos to application gallery instead of user one?

Comment: You need to do this as part of [authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) flow, using [OAuth dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth), [`Facebook::getLoginUrl`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/) or [`FB.login`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)

Comment: This is already the case if you uploading it to the `photos` connection of `user` (like `/me/photos`), see [`photo` object documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)

Comment: Doesn't work with v2.8 and v2.9 Graph API versions. StackOverflow should have a means to record and filter by applicable versions. Just a suggestion.